# How to convert ; separated string with Key=Value into a KeyValue pair in .net?

Tags: .net, frameworks

How can i split the following string into Key-Value Pair / Hash table ...

```
"Id=1000;Name=xyzabc;DB=1.2.3.4;DBUserName=admin;DBPassword"
```

I know it can be done by using string.Split() (One with ';', and then each result with '=').
I am looking for an easy and efficient way of doing it.

In short, instead of string manipulation is there an efficient way to convert the above highlighted text to access the value something like this...

```
someObject["Id"];//It should return 1000 
someObject["Name"];//It should return xyzabc 
someObject["DB"];//It should return xyzabc ..............
```

Does framework has any build in class to do it?

eg: The SQLConnectionBuilder will split the DBName, UserName, Password into its property, if we assign a connectionstring to the SQLConnectionBuilder

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail as to exactly what you need to accomplish? Maybe someone will have better way if you can exaplin what you are trying to do - beyond your original question.

Comment: @AshokPadmanabhan, I have added the explanation, now does it make sense ?

Comment: @AshokPadmanabhan its crystal clear what KBBwrite wants, no need for further info. I was looking for a AddRange method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.aspx) but no luck...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking your example about DbConnectionStringBuilder, if you look at the internals you'll find a method called `DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair` and it is not for the faint of heart. Skip that, and try something easy:

```
string input = "Id=1000;Name=xyzabc;DB=1.2.3.4;DBUserName=admin;DBPassword";

var kvp = input.Split(';')
    .Select(s => s.Split('='))
    .ToDictionary(s => s.First(), s => s.Last());
```

You'll get a Dictionary output that looks something like this:

```
Key=Id, Value=1000
Key=Name, Value=xyzabc
Key=DB, Value=1.2.3.4
Key=DBUserName, Value=admin
Key=DBPassword, Value=DBPassword
```

Of course, if you have duplicate keys in your string then a dictionary won't work. You might consider writing your own extension like .ToKeyValuePair(). I'm not quite sure about how to fix the key = value when you don't provide a value, but I'm too tired to think very hard about it.

Comment: This fails if the connection string contains Base64. Try to test with:
Name=Test;Value=VGVzdA==
The answer by Peter works in this case.

Answer (score 3):

To be honest I don't know of anything built in to help you out. Here are two ways that I would consider doing it,

```
Dictionary<string, string> keyValuePairs = new Dictionary<string,string>();

string original = "Id=1000;Name=xyzabc;DB=1.2.3.4;DBUserName=admin;DBPassword";

foreach(string keyValuePair in original.Split(new char[] {';'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
{
    string key = keyValuePair;
    string value = string.Empty;

    if (key.Contains('='))
    {
        key = keyValuePair.Substring(0, keyValuePair.IndexOf('='));
        value = keyValuePair.Substring(keyValuePair.IndexOf('=') + 1);
    }

    keyValuePairs.Add(key.Trim(), value.Trim());
}
```

Or a similar implementation,

```
Dictionary<string, string> keyValuePairs = new Dictionary<string,string>();

string original = "Id=1000;Name=xyzabc;DB=1.2.3.4;DBUserName=admin;DBPassword";

foreach(string keyValuePair in original.Split(new char[] {';'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
{
    string[] keyValues = keyValuePair.Split(new char[] { '=' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    if (keyValues.Length == 1)
    {
        keyValuePairs.Add(keyValues[0].Trim(), string.Empty);
    }
    else if (keyValues.Length == 2)
    {
        keyValuePairs.Add(keyValues[0].Trim(), keyValues[1].Trim());
    }
}
```

Both solutions give you a dictionary which gives the functionality to do what you are asking,

```
someObject["Id"];
```

I would also consider wrapping the above code into a class with a property like this,

```
private Dictionary<string, string> keyValuePairs = new Dictionary<string, string>();

// some combination of code above to decode the original string and add
// stuff to the dictionary

public string this[string key]
{
    get
    {
        if (keyValuePairs.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            return keyValuePairs[key];
        }
        else
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Because dictionaries throw an exception if you reference a key that is not in the dictionary.